# Web scraping , spliting with space text in same <a>

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how can I split the text data inside  tags.

**Source**

```
   <a class="s14oa9nh-0 jgjg5" href="blablabla.com" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">
        <div class="tag">differentforEveryAtagText</div>
        508,22 $
        <span class="s14oa9nh-2 adsad3">
          <img src="blalblalbal.svg" />
        </span>
    </a>
```

**Desired output:**

> DescriptionText - 508,22$

```
found_tags = product.find_all('a')

for tag in found_tags:
    tag
    print(tag.text)
```

**My code gives me:**

> DescriptionText508,22$

want to give space or arrange these as 2 different block , how can I do that ,DescriptionText is dynamic and price is too.  thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build loop to locate both `<a>` and `<div>` texts, and use it to format the result

```
found_tags = product.find_all('a')

for tag in found_tags:
    all_text = tag.text
    description_text = tag.find('div', attrs={'class': 'tag'}).text
    result = all_text.replace(description_text, description_text + ' - ')
    print(result) # prints DescriptionText - 508,22$
```

Comment: description text can be change its dynamic for every product

Comment: @BCA this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always `DescriptionText`, you could use regex.

```py
import re

text = "DescriptionText508"
text = re.sub(r'(DescriptionText)', r'\1 - ', text)
print(text)

Output: DescriptionText - 508
```

The brackets create a group, which \1 refers to when specifying a replacement. So `DescriptionText508` is replaced by `DescriptionText - 508`.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over it's children and check for every child,

if it's a 'Tag', return it's text.

if it's a 'NavigableString'(means it's just a string), use it as you wish

```
a = product.find_all('a')[0]

for child in a.children:
  if isinstance(child, bs4.NavigableString):
    print(child)
  else:
    print(child.text)
```

Of course you can loop over the Tag's children using recursion, it's just up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Find the item and use `next_sibling`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<a class="s14oa9nh-0 jgjg5" href="blablabla.com" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">
        <div class="tag">DescriptionText</div>
        508,22 $
        <span class="s14oa9nh-2 adsad3">
          <img src="blalblalbal.svg" />
        </span>
    </a>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(item.find_next('div').text + "-"+ item.find_next('div').next_sibling.strip() )
```